How to remove Title page from Content
I have the following latex script (I kept only the relevant parts):
\documentclass[twoside]{mitthesis}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}

\Author{Name 1}{Department of Physics}

\Degree{Doctor of Philosophy in Physics}{Department of Physics}

\Supervisor{Name 2}{Professor of Physics}

\Acceptor{Name 3}{Professor of Physics}{}%

\DegreeDate{September}{2024}

\ThesisDate{Sept 1, 2024}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\end{document}

When I compile it, the first entry in the "Contents" is "Title page" which corresponds to page number 1. How can I remove it from the Contents, as I don't want the first page to be part of it? Thank you!

Which version of the mitthesis document class do you employ? When I compile your test document on my system (MacTeX2024, with all updates applied), the log file says that LaTeX uses Document Class: mitthesis 2024/07/19 MIT Thesis Template (JHL). (The log file also reports that the mitthesis class is built on the report document class, version 2024/02/08 v1.4n.) Importantly, I am unable to reproduce the situation you say you encounter with this particular setup.

Could it be, that you do not mean a "Title page" in the table of contents but in the bookmarks? In this case, you should not remove it, because it is useful. However, if you have an entry in the table of contents, an update would help to remove it. AFAIK this has been removed this year.

Why the 'close' vote?

@Mico Because the issue does not happen with an up-to-date version of the class, so an available update does solve it and therefore the close reason of using a not up-to-date version is valid.

Up-to-date versions of mitthesis do not make an entry “Title page” to the table of contents any longer. They only make an entry “Title page” to the bookmarks:

Older versions of the class indeed also produce an entry to the “Contents”:

So to remove the entry in the “Contents” just update. And up-to-date TeX Live 2024, e.g., provides version 1.14 2024/07/19 of the class, which generates only the bookmark but not the entry to the table of contents. For an update you can copy mitthesis.cls to your Overleaf project. At least version 1.14 2024/07/19 seems to work with the LaTeX version of Overleaf, if you are using either TeX Live 2024 or 2023 (note: Overleaf provides several TeX Live versions).
I would not recommend to remove the entry to the bookmarks. However, if you need to do this (after an update to a new version of the class), you can use the following hack:
\documentclass[twoside]{mitthesis}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}

\Author{Name 1}{Department of Physics}

\Degree{Doctor of Philosophy in Physics}{Department of Physics}

\Supervisor{Name 2}{Professor of Physics}

\Acceptor{Name 3}{Professor of Physics}{}%

\DegreeDate{September}{2024}

\ThesisDate{Sept 1, 2024}

\begingroup
\renewcommand*\pdfbookmark[3][]{}% Not recommended hack!
\maketitle
\endgroup

\tableofcontents

\end{document}

You could try a similar hack for old versions of mitthesis:
\documentclass[twoside]{mitthesis}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}

\Author{Name 1}{Department of Physics}

\Degree{Doctor of Philosophy in Physics}{Department of Physics}

\Supervisor{Name 2}{Professor of Physics}

\Acceptor{Name 3}{Professor of Physics}{}%

\DegreeDate{September}{2024}

\ThesisDate{Sept 1, 2024}

\begingroup
\renewcommand*{\addcontentsline}{3}{%
  \pdfbookmark[0]{Title page}{titlepage}% optional to add a bookmark
}
\maketitle
\endgroup

\tableofcontents

\end{document}

This would remove the entry in the table of contents and replace it by a bookmark only for old versions of the class (but you can comment the \pdfbookmark line to also not add a bookmark).
But instead I would recommend to update the class.

The OP has set the overleaf tag, which made me ask myself whether the version of mitthesis that's currently provided by Overleaf might be dated. Sure enough, Overleaf still uses version 2023/11/02, not 2024/07/19.

@Mico This is why I've added the last example. However, the up-to-date version of the class even works with TeX Live 2023, so Overleaf users can use a local copy of an up-to-date mitthesis.cls and I would still recommend to do such an update.

I just logged on to my Overleaf account (I rarely do so...), compiled the OP's test file, and was able to reproduce their issue with the unwanted entry in the ToC. Overleaf's log file says that as of today (1 Aug 2024),
mitthesis 2023/11/02

is in use. Unfortunately, this isn't quite the latest version. On the CTAN (and on my MacTeX2024 system, with all the latest updates installed), version 2024/07/19 is listed as the most recent version. And, as reported in an earlier comment, the latest version of mitthesis does not generate the issue the OP is trying to fix.
May I suggest that you contact the Overleaf Helpdesk -- their LaTeX support staff are top notch! -- and ask them for help installing version 2024/07/19 of mitthesis.cls in your working directory? Alternatively, if you're so inclined, do find your way to https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mitthesis and copy the file mitthesis.cls to your working folder.
